# Pass div contents into ng-show angular function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, web

I have this div:

```
<div class="col-md-3" ng-show="hideYN('hideme?')">hideme?</div>
```

And this Angular function in a controller (where `$scope.test1` is bound to an input field):

```
$scope.hideYN = function(val) {
 if (val.indexOf($scope.test1) == -1) {
   return false;
 }
 return true;
}
```

Basically, this is functioning as a searchable grid of divs, with divs being hidden whose content doesn't match the input value (`$scope.test1`).

However, I don't want to hard code the string parameter of the `hideYN()`function. Is there a way to pass the contents of the div to this function?

Comment: How is the content for these `<div>`s generated? If it is generated from the  server (in this example php) it could look like:

`<div ng-show="hideYN('<?php echo $var ?>'"><?php echo $var ?></div>`

I would also suggest if you have an array of values within Angular you can use an `ng-repeat` to generate your content, for then you can use `ng-filter` with your input. [See Angular docs on filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

Comment: Thanks, I implemented something similar with ng-repeat in the end.